# Adding UIButtons in a UIView with dynamic width in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to add UIButtons in a UIView, buttons width will change depending on their title. So it could be one button in a row or 3 buttons in a row. If there is no space in same row button should be added in the next row. Something like this
[image]

and UIView height should increase if more lines are added up-to a certain height.

I am thinking to start with UIStackViews but not sure how to achieve this functionality. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: UICollectionView is made for this type of layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UICollectionView` using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` would do this by default. The only thing you would have to do is update the height of the collevtionView to match its content size if you don't want it to certainly scroll.

Using a `UIStackView` would require you to calculate the the size of every button and move down to a new row when they don't fit. While that doesn't sound to hard, it's a lot of layout math you'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a custom button generator

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit

        class ButtonGenerator {
            private var buttonTitleArray = [String]()
            private var buttonBackgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
            private var buttonFontColor: UIColor = UIColor.black
            private var passedFunctionCall: Selector?
            private var passedParentView = UIScrollView()
            private var parentViewWidth = CGFloat()
            private var desiredMargin = CGFloat()
            private var buttonsToReturn = [UIButton]()

            func setButtonStyle(bkgColor:UIColor,fontColor:UIColor) {
                buttonBackgroundColor = bkgColor
                buttonFontColor = fontColor
            }

            func setMargin(to margin:CGFloat) {
                desiredMargin = margin
            }

            func addButtons(to parentView:UIScrollView,withTitles passedTitles [String],calling function:Selector){
                //Receive Passed Arguments
                passedParentView = parentView
                parentViewWidth = parentView.frame.width
                buttonTitleArray = passedTitles
                passedFunctionCall = function

                //Track current origin coordinates
                var XPos = desiredMargin
                var YPos = desiredMargin
                var buttonHeight = CGFloat()

                for i in 0..<buttonTitleArray.count {
                    let buttonToAdd = UIButton(type: .custom)
                    buttonToAdd.backgroundColor = buttonBackgroundColor
                    buttonToAdd.setTitleColor(buttonFontColor, for: .normal)
                    buttonToAdd.setTitle(buttonTitleArray[i], for: .normal)
                    buttonToAdd.sizeToFit()
                    buttonHeight = buttonToAdd.frame.height
                    buttonToAdd.addTarget(self, action: passedFunctionCall!, for: .touchUpInside)

                    if XPos + buttonToAdd.frame.width < parentViewWidth-(2*desiredMargin) {
                        //buttonToAdd won't be clipped --> Okay to add to current row
                        buttonToAdd.frame.origin.x = XPos
                        buttonToAdd.frame.origin.y = YPos

                //no change in row --> only update X position
                XPos += buttonToAdd.frame.width + desiredMargin
            }
            else {
                //buttonToAdd will be clipped --> display on next row
                XPos = desiredMargin
                YPos += buttonHeight + desiredMargin

                //set button position
                buttonToAdd.frame.origin.x = XPos
                buttonToAdd.frame.origin.y = YPos

                //update X position
                XPos += buttonToAdd.frame.width + desiredMargin
            }
            //Add Button to return array
            buttonsToReturn.append(buttonToAdd)
        }

        //Set YPos to position of content bottom
        YPos += buttonHeight + desiredMargin

        //Set content size of the parent scroll view to the generated height
        passedParentView.contentSize = CGSize(width: parentViewWidth, height: YPos)

        //Add the buttons to the scroll view
        for i in 0..<buttonsToReturn.count {
            passedParentView.addSubview(buttonsToReturn[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Then to call the button generator in your ViewController you'd add the following:

```
    let btnGen = ButtonGenerator()
    btnGen.setButtonStyle(bkgColor: UIColor.white, fontColor: UIColor.blue)
    btnGen.setMargin(to: 10)
    btnGen.addButtons(to: hashtagScrollView, withTitles: PostModel.Post.genericMusicHashtags, calling:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)))
```

Also, because of the selector, you'll have to add an @objc func to your ViewController Class.

```
    @objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
         print(sender.titleLabel!.text!)
    }
```

It doesn't have the limiting height functionality, but you should be able to modify the button generator to include an if statement to stop adding buttons.